# Bamboo: error on svn checkout - version mismatch

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am having troubles checking out my svn repository (see error below).
When I restart the plan it runs fine.
The curious thing is that the version number which is claiming the process does not exist in this repository!
My guess is that there is a svn-cache which is mixing up the jobs and its references to the svn repository.
I already added a task at the beginning of my job which is eleminating the svn folder... but still it is having this problem.
Have to say that this plan is a child-plan and the parent itself also is a child. I programmed kind of a release-cascade of related projects and the error must be there. Also the parent and its children have Bamboo-branches.

Any idea is appreciated!

Bamboo 4.4.2 on Suse

Here is the trace:

> 14-Apr-2014 18:09:36  Error occurred while running Task 'Checkout
>   Default Repository(1)'. This build will fail. Caused by:  14-Apr-2014
>   18:09:36  java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.RepositoryException: Failed to
>   checkout source code to revision '22530' for
>   http://svn.bla.com/svn/cliente/trunk/projectx
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.executor.RetryingTaskExecutor.rerun(RetryingTaskExecutor.java:132)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.executor.RetryingTaskExecutor.runTask(RetryingTaskExecutor.java:88)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.executor.RetryingTaskExecutor.retry(RetryingTaskExecutor.java:191)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.executor.RetryingTaskExecutor.retry(RetryingTaskExecutor.java:176)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs.task.VcsCheckoutTask.execute(VcsCheckoutTask.java:109)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.executeTasks(TaskExecutorImpl.java:187)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskExecutorImpl.execute(TaskExecutorImpl.java:93)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.tasks.ExecuteBuildTask.call(ExecuteBuildTask.java:87)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent.build(DefaultBuildAgent.java:206)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl.waitAndPerformBuild(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:103)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent$1.run(DefaultBuildAgent.java:111)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.build.pipeline.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:52)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36  Caused by:
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.RepositoryException: Failed to
>   checkout source code to revision '22530' for
>   http://svn.bla.com/svn/cliente/trunk/projectx
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.checkout(SvnRepository.java:1156)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.checkout(SvnRepository.java:1178)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.retrieveSourceCodeWithException(SvnRepository.java:708)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.retrieveSourceCodeWithCleanup(SvnRepository.java:642)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.retrieveSourceCode(SvnRepository.java:584)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs.task.VcsCheckoutTask.fillWorkingDirFromVcs(VcsCheckoutTask.java:180)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs.task.VcsCheckoutTask.access$100(VcsCheckoutTask.java:46)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs.task.VcsCheckoutTask$1.call(VcsCheckoutTask.java:114)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs.task.VcsCheckoutTask$1.call(VcsCheckoutTask.java:110)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.executor.RetryingTaskExecutor.rerun(RetryingTaskExecutor.java:108)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          ... 12 more 14-Apr-2014 18:09:36    Caused
>   by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160006: No such
>   revision 22530 14-Apr-2014 18:09:36   svn: E175002: PROPFIND of
>   '/svn/client/!svn/vcc/default': 500 Internal Server Error
>   (http://svn.bla.com) 14-Apr-2014 18:09:36         at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getResourceProperties(DAVUtil.java:81)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineProperties(DAVUtil.java:249)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVUtil.getBaselineInfo(DAVUtil.java:184)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.checkPath(DAVRepository.java:223)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:720)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:14)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:9)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:291)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:777)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          at
>   com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.svn.SvnRepository.checkout(SvnRepository.java:1152)
>   14-Apr-2014 18:09:36          ... 21 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved: I used variables to generate the repository path and wanted to control the svn-path from the bamboo variables. This intention of having a dynamic task killed my process and mixed the revision/checkout.